# RoR SCSS/CSS out of function

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

In my Rails app. This is how my custom.css.scss file looks like:

```
@import "bootstrap";

/* mixins, variables, etc. */

$grayMediumLight: #eaeaea;

@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



/* footer */

footer {
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  border-top: 1px solid $grayMediumLight;
  color: $grayLight;
  a {
    color: $gray;
    &:hover {
      color: $grayDarker;
    }
  }
  small {
    float: left;
  }
  ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    li {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

And I have a _footer.html.erb partial here:

```
<footer class="footer">
  <small>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/siaw23">Twitter:</a>
    Siaw23
  </small>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://music.twitter.com/">Music :D</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

And my application.html.erb like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Kalendar</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>
<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</body>
</html>
```

I have bootstrap in my Gemfile and i have run `bundle install` but the css effect is failing to work. Any reason why? Could use some help here.

This is how my page looks like currently:

[image]

This is my application.css

```
/*
*= require_tree .
*= require bootstrap

*/
```

Comment: Can you share application.css ?

Comment: @muttonlamb application.css is empty :/

Comment: I added my application.css content

Comment: Actually by looking at your screenshot, the styles from your custom.css are not in use either. Check 2 things: 1) look at the source code and see if your css files are loaded. In development mode they shouldn't be precompiled so you can find them quickly. 2) check your configuration files and see if you didnt disable any assets options.

Comment: i already figured it out. just had to restart the server. and everything was ok.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you installed the bootstrap gem or added your bootstrap css files in the assets or vender folders, you still need to let rails know to compile the bootstrap assets.

In your Application.css add the require line before `*= require_tree.` With:

```
*= require bootstrap
```

You can do the same for other stylesheets such as *= require filename (omit the file extension, rails will detect it)

The same goes with javascript but with a slightly different syntax

Application.js

```
//= require bootstrap
```

Comment: my application.css looks like this `/*
*= require_tree .
*= require bootstrap

*/`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like  you are trying to load the bootstrap stuff before it is required.

With the asset pipeline in rails the order of loading is important as the files are packed up and concatenated.

Try placing the `require tree .` after you require bootstrap, this should help ensure that the contents are available and not overwritten.

It's occasionally necessary to restart the development server when making these changes too.

Comment: well this is the content  `
*= require_self

*= require bootstrap
*= require_tree .
`but it changes nothing.